# Color-change of element does not work properly on mobile browsers (iPad)

Tags: css, cross-browser, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce to build an ecommerce site ([as seen here](http://www.demoy.se/product/dionne-piece-of-my-heart/)) and I've changed the color of the "Add to Cart" button using this code:

```
.woocommerce a.button.alt, .woocommerce button.button.alt, .woocommerce input.button.alt, .woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt, .woocommerce #content input.button.alt, .woocommerce-page a.button.alt, .woocommerce-page button.button.alt, .woocommerce-page input.button.alt, .woocommerce-page #respond input#submit.alt, .woocommerce-page #content input.button.alt {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(26, 22, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 22, 27) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent !important;
    border-color: rgb(26, 22, 27) !important;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

For some reason, the color change just happens on the computer screen. When I look at the site on an iPad or an iPhone, the add to cart button has a blue color instead of the black color that I want. I have tried the code on another site (different domain and host) and it worked fine and turn the button black for all devices.

What could the problem be?

Comment: maybe a cache problem ??

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you're using

```
 -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(26, 22, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 22, 27) 100%)
```

Which is unique to mozilla. Since the iDevices don't use mozilla, it won't render properly.

The equivalents for other browsers would be

```
-webkit-gradient //Safari, chrome, etc. Webkit browsers
-webkit-linear-gradient // see above
-o-linear-gradient //Opera
-linear-gradient
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix the problem.

Comment: @Charlie if this answer helped you, then please upvote it and mark it as accepted. By doing so, you will receive rep (accepting an answer).